# How to read a structured text file and create a structure for it in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, text, structure, read-data

I have a text file which contains results for many time steps. for each time step, some basic info was saved in the first line, followed by a matrix that contains other data for this step. The matrix size can differ at every time step and it is not predefined.

How to create a structure based on such text file?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. the results in text file looks like this:

```
 time=   4.3750000000000001E-004           3           7           4           1   4.9999989999999998E-004
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  5.6569E+08  7.5717E+08  5.6569E+08  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00

 time=   5.0000000000000001E-004           3           5           3           0   4.9999989999999998E-004
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  2.3593E+08  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00

 time=   1.8125000000000001E-003           3           3           3           1   1.8749999000000001E-003
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  3.9138E+07  0.0000E+00
  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume each new set for data starts by `time=` and ends by spaced line, you can use the following code sample:

```
%Open text file for reading (assume file name is 'Data.txt').
f = fopen('Data.txt', 'r');

%Initialize main (store data) to empty matrix.
main = [];

%Initialize index to 1
i = 1;

while (~feof(f))
    %Read single line from text file (as long string).
    S = fgets(f);

    if (strfind(S, 'time') > 0)
        %Remove 'time= ' from the beginning of S.
        S = strrep(S, 'time=', '');

        %Convert string to array of numbers.
        T = sscanf(S, '%f ');

        %Store vector T to main(i).sub1
        main(i).sub1 = T';

        %Set A to empty matrix - prepare for filling with new data.
        A = [];

        %Read next line from text file (as long string).
        S = fgets(f);        
    end    

    %Convert string to array of numbers.
    L = sscanf(S, '%f ');

    if (isempty(L) || feof(f))
        %Store matrix A to main(i).sub2
        main(i).sub2 = A;

        %Advance i (data index) by 1.
        i = i + 1;
    else
        %In case A is not empty, concatenate T to bottom of A.
        A = [A; L'];
    end
end

%Close file.
fclose(f);
```

---

Result:

```
>>main(1)

sub1 =

   4.3750e-04   3.0000e+00   7.0000e+00   4.0000e+00   1.0000e+00   5.0000e-04

sub2 =

           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
           0           0   565690000   757170000   565690000           0           0
           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
           0           0           0           0           0           0           0


>>main(2)

sub1 =

   0.00050   3.00000   5.00000   3.00000   0.00000   0.00050

sub2 =

           0           0           0           0           0
           0           0   235930000           0           0
           0           0           0           0           0


>>main(3)

sub1 =

   0.0018125   3.0000000   3.0000000   3.0000000   1.0000000   0.0018750

sub2 =

          0          0          0
          0   39138000          0
          0          0          0
```

Comment: Thanks Rotem! I'm thinking about saving the structure in a way that all the first line of a time step will be in a substructure 'main(i).sub1' which contains 1x7 elements, and the matrix under each time step will be main(i).sub2, this contains MxN elements (M, N varies in each time step). here i refers to the i-th time step. And I guess the edited version of the data in my question doesn't show the clear structure of the text file anymore...

Comment: Sorry for editing your post incorrectly (it looked too messy). Can you please re-edit your post. Make it clear how to get MxN elements from the text file format. Make clear the structure you like. Please don't post all the content of your text file - post just enough to make it clear.

Comment: Hi Rotem, no problem! Now the structure is clear in the post.

Comment: I tested my updated code using Octave, I hope it's working with Matlab too.

Comment: Hi Rotem! Thank you very much! It is exactly what I want!